# Invalid hook call, from Reactjs to Nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have been a while outside the **ReactJS** world, and I decided to come back and give a try with **NextJS**. However I am getting a **Invalid Hook Call** issue.

I'm trying to convert my ReactJS project to a NextJS project. I'll show the code in a shorter format, just for the example.

**Here is my Reactjs:**

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

**App.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

import MainPage from './components/MainPage';


class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <Router>
          <main>
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path='/' component={MainPage}/>
            </Switch>
          </main>
        </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**MainPage.js**

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';

import './MainPage.css';

const MainPage = () => {
    return (
        <Fragment>
            <div>
                  Hello There :-)
            </div>
       <Fragment>
    );
};

export default MainPage;
```

**Here is my Nextjs:**

**_app.js**

```
import '../styles/globals.css'

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}

export default MyApp
```

**index.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

import MainPage from './components/MainPage';


class App extends Component {
  render() { **// not sure about the render**
    return (
        <Router>
          <main>
            <Switch> **// I think was switched to Routes**
              <Route exact path='/' component={MainPage}/> **// I think was switched to element**
            </Switch>
          </main>
        </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**MainPage.js**

```
import styles from '../styles/Home.module.css'

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>    
      <main className={styles.main}>
        <h1 className={styles.title}>
          Welcome to <a href="https://nextjs.org">Next.js!</a>
        </h1>
      </main>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: idk what went wrong, but NextJs has a built-in folder-based routing system. Maybe you may want to switch to using that

Comment: You can remove all of the routing logic bc it's built-in as Boa said - https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/introduction - Your current `pages/index.js` code should be replaced file with the code from `MainPage.js`

Answer (score 0):

you don't need react router inside next js because it has a pages folder that whatever folder you create there will be your route for example if you create an
about folder and an index.js inside of it the index.js file will be shown to you on /about route;

for homepage you can create a components folder near pages folder and move your MainPage.js there and then import it in your index.js inside your pages folder;